# Can I go to any Schengen country with my German Schengen visa?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines, bookings

I have a Schengen visa category C issued by the German Embassy in my home country. Am I able to visit multiple Schengen countries with this Class C Schengen visa? Could I start my trip in another Schengen country, such as Hungary, and go to Germany later in my trip?

Answer (score 2):

If your visa is valid for `SCHENGENER STAATEN`, then it is valid for travel anywhere in the Schengen zone (within its period of validity, allowed length of stay and number of entries). You do not have to enter the Schengen area through Germany.

One **caveat**, however: If it is the first trip you use the visa for, the *purpose of travel you described in your visa application* must still apply to the trip you're actually making. You can add "side quests" to other Schengen countries at will -- but if you abandon the original premise of the trip and you're found out at the entry interview or later, you risk the visa being cancelled (or *annulled*, if they think you never had any intention of following it, which is even worse). This holds especially if your trip changes so much that Germany is no longer its *main* destination.

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt answer it really addressed the question. I'll be following the application. The change is the travel plan was Munich-Germany, Prague, Vienna then Budapest. But after having the visa the program changed to Budapest then Vienna, then Prague then Munich

Comment: @O.Sh: If Munich is still clearly your main destination, then there should be no problems. However, if you only selected to apply to Germany based on the fallback rule that "if no main destination can be identified, apply to the first country you enter", then it would be prudent to be prepared to present a convincing explanation for when and how your plans changed. In that case it _may_ also help avoid trouble if you have a layover somewhere in Germany on the way to Budapest.